# After upgrading to EF 6.0.2 query started getting StackOverflowException

Tags: entity-framework, include, left-join, stack-overflow

When I upgraded from v 5 to v 6.0.2, one of my queries started giving me a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I replaced all of my Include clauses with left joins (i.e. join with a DefaultIfEmpty clause), and that fixed the stack overflow issue.  However, I don't believe that I had any recursions in my model. The query did work with Version 5 of entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in EF6 the `UseDatabaseNullSematics` is by default set to `false` which causes creating bigger queries. This was tracked here https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1579. You can get the same queries you had in EF5 just by flipping this flag to `true` however the queries may sometime yield unexpected (from a C# programmer perspective) results. The issues is being addressed in EF6.1 where the queries should be smaller even if `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` is set to `true`. For more details see:

- https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1598
- https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1621